# for every different group of a specific value

Tags: r, dataframe

I load data in a data frame and they are having this format:

```
number            value   day  
2                 2       21/3/2010 
2                 3       22/3/2010
2                 4       23/3/2010
3                 2       21/3/2010
3                 3       22/3/2010
3                 5       23/3/2010
3                 4       24/3/2010
```

I try to take the plot of the dataframe based on column number for the column value and in the x-axis having the day and in y-axis having the value. Making two subplots one for number=2 and one for number=3. Is there any efficient way?

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient?"

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried thus far and explain how it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
sapply(unique(df$number), function (x) plot(df$day[df$number == x], df$value[df$number == x]) )
```

something like that? reproducible code in your OP would help

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit too much, but it a scalable solution (you can use it for n groups)

I would extract the unique "numbers" (the variable you are trying to group), make subsets iteratively and plot

```
un_numbers <- unique(numbers)

for (i in 1:length(un_numbers){

data.subset <- subset(data,numbers== un_numbers[i])

hist(data.subset)}
```